Lift of a homotopy equivalence to the universal covers is a quasi-isometry
Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be two finite connected graphs, and let $f$ be a homotopy equivalence between them. Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be the universal covers of $G_1$ and $G_2$, respectively. Let $\tilde{f}$ be the lift of $f$ between $T_1$ and $T_2$. Then, it is known that $\tilde{f}$ is a homotopy equivalence. My question is the following:
Is $\tilde{f}$ a quasi-isometry?
My try: I think it will be a quasi-isometry. The fundamental group of $G_i$ is quasi-isometric to $T_i$ for $i=1,2$, and hence $T_1$
and $T_2$
are quasi-isometric as $G_1$
is isomorphic to $G_2$
. But I could not show that this quasi-isometry is a finite distance apart from $\tilde{f}$.
Thanks in advance.

What do you think? What did you try to solve this problem? What tools do you know to answer this type of questions?

@Moishe Kohan I think it will be a quasi-isometry. The fundamental group of $G_i$ is quasi-isometric to $T_i$ for $i=1,2$, and hence $T_1$ and $T_2$ are quasi-isometric as $G_1$ is isomorphic to $G_2$. But I could show that this quasi-isometry is a finite distance apart from $\tilde{f}$.

You should include all this in your a question instead of a comment.

In the above comment of mine, I mean I could not show that this quasi-isometry is a finite distance apart from $\tilde{f}$.

You should verify that if $G\times X_i\to X_i, i=1,2$ are geometric actions of a (finitely generated) group on geodesic metric spaces $X_i$, and $f: X_1\to X_2$ is an equivariant coarsely Lipschitz map, then $f$ is a quasi-isometry. Start by proving that the image of $f$ is Hausdorff-close to $X_2$.
